# SHOW PROCESSLIST: show processes from all sessions

Tags: mariadb, process

`SHOW PROCESSLIST` shows the list of processes for the current user and session only.

Is there a way for the current user to list all their processes for **all** currently opened sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obtain this info from `information_schema.PROCESSLIST`. If your user have `PROCESS` privilege, and you need to view only your processes - use `WHERE user = USER()` filter.

[Link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/information-schema-processlist-table/)